Can't share existing desktop after 20.04 to 24.04 upgrade
I'm running an Intel box with Gnome. There is only one local user.
I've been using tightvnc with 20.04 to share existing desktop via an SSH tunnel connected to localhost. This has worked flawlessly nd allowed me to connect to the lock screen and type the password for the default user, log in, and view/edit the desktop including any running programs.
Since upgrading to 24.04 this functionality has disappeared. I tried using RDP bundled with 24.04. This works, but only if the user's screen is left unlocked. If the local inactivity timeout locks the screen, it no longer works. While the physical machine is in a relatively secure location, I'd like to have the same functionality. If the Ubuntu experts have a way to use RDP to connect to a locked screen, that would be acceptable, but I haven't figured out a way to do so. I can use port 3390 instead of 3389 and get a new session but that doesn't give me access to the existing running programs.
I've tried reinstalling VNC to regain the "it just works" functionality that I had. Various searches suggested x0vncserver (but some sources described it as a proof-of-concept that is inefficient) x11vnc, tightvncserver, and tigervnc. I have encountered the following errors:
Refuses to start or gives one or more of the following:

Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Unable to open display :0
Connects but gives a grey screen with an X cursor
Connects but gives a black screen with arrow cursor

There have been some suggestions to adjust XAUTHORITY but they haven't been too clear as to what to set, whether as root or the local user, and several attempts don't seem to help.
The problem that I'm trying to solve:

Allow local screen to time out and lock on inactivity but leave programs running (this is working)
Allow remote login to share active screen or view locked screen and type password in the box to open and control mirror of existing screen.
Have this behavior automatically available on a reboot.

If RDP can do this, I'm happy to change.
If VNC can do this on 24.04 I'd love to figure out how.
Any help would be appreciated. I think I'm close. This seemed pretty easy for a newbie like me on 20.04 but I'm banging my head against the wall trying to get something to work since the upgrade. I've considered formatting everything and reverting to 20.04 but really don't want to do that. There has to be something simple I'm missing.
